# Does StringFormat in a TextBox make any sense?

Tags: c#, xaml

If I have a TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Voltage, StringFormat={}{0} kV}" />
```

and the property Voltage is e.g. 50, I get "50 kV" in my TextBox. This is what I intended.

But now, if the user wants to enter a new value say 40 and types "40 kV" he gets a red border, because there is a FormatException converting back the value.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '40 kV' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Voltage; DataItem='VMO_VoltageDefinition' (HashCode=19837180); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Die Eingabezeichenfolge hat das falsche Format.
```

I don't think that the users of my program will accept this.

So am I doing something wrong or is this feature just not usable in a reasonable way with a TextBox?

Comment: My WPF/xaml knowledge is not good enough to answer this directly, but I've seen this done by defining `Voltage` as its own type, and then define a formatter which can convert back and forth to a string formatting. This is quite neat as allows the user to enter `40kV` or `400V` or `1mV` etc.

Comment: I usually prefer to keep the prefix/suffix outside the text box. Though I do like @Jamiec's option as it allows user to enter their own.

Comment: I like Jamiec's option as well, but be aware of additional cost: Most of the time your model will have property of primitive type (int or double) and you need to convert it to your custom type and vice versa in viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringFormat` is property of `Binding` markup extension and theoretically can be used in any binding. However, mostly it makes sense with one-way bindings only.

You are right, that stringformat does not makes much sense in  TextBox.

You can workaround it by converter as David suggested, but I recommend you to display the unit in TextBlock outside TextBox:

```
<DockPanel>
   <TextBlock Text="kV" DockPanel.Dock="Right />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Voltage}" />
</DockPanel>
```

This feels more natural and gives much better user experience.

alternatively, you can create custom control derived from TextBox with new property called Unit or Description, or whatever and modify the control templeate so it will show the unit. Then the final markup could look like this:

```
<my:TextBox Text="{Binding Voltage}" Description="kV" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest usage of converter:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Voltage, Converter={StaticResource VoltageToString}}" />
```

Where:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <mstf:VoltageToStringx:Key="VoltageToString" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And codebehind:

```
public class VoltageToString: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)value).ToString() + " kV";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return int.Parse((string).Replace(" kV",""));
    }
}
```

That is just an basic example, but you should get the idea how to make it more sophisticated.